# docker-compose for nginx and nodejs server

Tags: nginx, docker, node.js, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    server:
        build:
            context: ../../
            dockerfile: ./packages/website/Dockerfile
        command: node /cutting/index.js
        environment:
            PORT: 8000
            NODE_ENV: production
        restart: always
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: ./nginx/Dockerfile
        command: tail -f /dev/null
        depends_on:
            - server
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        restart: always
```

And the following `nginx.conf`:

```
worker_processes 1;

user nobody nogroup;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log /tmp/logs/nginx.error.log;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    accept_mutex off;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    access_log /tmp/logs/nginx.access.log combined;
    sendfile on;

    server {
        proxy_http_version 1.1; # this is essential for chunked responses to work

        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name frontend;

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types application/javascript text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location /static/  {
            alias /static/;
        }

        location  / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

            # UNCOMMENT LINE BELOW IF THIS IS BEHIND A SSL PROXY
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass   http://localhost:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

If this creates 2 containers how can I get nginx to see the localhost:8000 on the other container?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use the container's `name` as you defined it in `docker-compose.yml`. Docker provides the IP addresses for the named containers via DNS within each container, and updates them if the containers are updated.

In this case, you called it `server`, so that is what you would use.

```
    proxy_pass http://server:8000;
```

Documentation: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: My man. I spent all day contemplating hulk smashing my laptop until your answer calmed me down off the ledge. This deserves 10x upvotes. I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use upstream like:

```
upstream backend {
    server express-server:81; #you container/service name
}
```

and then use:

```
proxy_pass http://backend
```